# Pivot the SQL Server table and also merge two columns simultaneously

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have following table named as 'TABLE'.

[image]

and My desired output should be as following.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything so far to solve the problem?

Comment: Show the SQL that you have tried, its better to have table definitions are text rather than pictures too

Comment: I am not too familiar with sql-server so my code is not giving me result. rather your reply would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query will return your expected result:

```
SELECT  Model, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN Number = 1 THEN Series + '-' + Code ELSE '' END) AS SeriesCode1,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Number = 2 THEN Series + '-' + Code ELSE '' END) AS SeriesCode2
FROM TestTable
GROUP BY Model
```

Demo with sample data:

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE (Model VARCHAR (10), Series VARCHAR (10), Code VARCHAR (10), Number INT);

INSERT INTO @TestTable (Model, Series, Code, Number) VALUES 
('AB708', 'D07', '2015-01', 1),
('AB708', 'D07', '2014-11', 2),
('CB708', 'ED07', '2011-08', 1),
('CB708', 'ED07', '2012-10', 2);

SELECT  Model, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN Number = 1 THEN Series + '-' + Code ELSE '' END) AS SeriesCode1,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Number = 2 THEN Series + '-' + Code ELSE '' END) AS SeriesCode2
FROM @TestTable
GROUP BY Model
```

Output:

```
Model   SeriesCode1     SeriesCode2
--------------------------------------
AB708   D07-2015-01     D07-2014-11
CB708   ED07-2011-08    ED07-2012-10
```

Comment: `concat` is not available for `SQL Server 2008`

Comment: @Squirrel Thanks, I have missed the tag, updated in the answer